# Следующий високосный год

Tags: python, циклы

Перепробовал разные варианты, не могу найти решение. Определить какой год это не сложно, но я не могу понять как вывести следующий год.

Задача:
Создайте программу, которая запрашивает у пользователя год и сообщает вам, когда наступит следующий високосный год.

Должно быть вот так:

```
Year?: 2019

Year 2019 next leap year 2020

Year?: 2020

Year 2020 is leap year and next leap year 2024
```

Мой код:

```
i = int(input("Year?:  "))
while i % 400==0 and i % 4 == 0 and i % 100!=0:
    print("Year is a leap year", i, "next leap year", i + 4 )
   
else:
    print("Year", i, "next leap year", i +1 )
```

Comment: Вывести следующий год очень просто: ``i+1``. Вот только совсем необязательно он будет високосным.

Comment: вы бы оформили проверку в функицю `isLeap(y)`, тогда бы после ввода проверили `if isLeap(i) ....` а иначе `while(!isLeap(++i)); ` и потом вывод (код условный питона не знаю)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то как-то так считаем "в лоб":

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    """Determine whether a year is a leap year."""

    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

current_year = int(input("Year?:  "))
next_leap_year = current_year + 1
while not is_leap_year(next_leap_year):
    next_leap_year += 1

print(f'Year {current_year} {("","is leap year and ")[is_leap_year(current_year)]}next leap year {next_leap_year}')
```

- Выделяем определение високосного года в отдельную функцию
- Ищем следующий високосный год начиная с года, следующего за введённым
- Выводим информацию о том, високосный ли текущий год, и следующий високосный год

Comment: Cпасибо огромное !

Answer (score 5):

Проверяем высокосный ли это год. Если нет к текущему году прибавляем еще `y % 4`.

```
from calendar import isleap

def next_leap(y):
    y += 4 - y % 4
    return y if isleap(y) else y + 4 

print(next_leap(2012)) # 2016
print(next_leap(2017)) # 2020
print(next_leap(2020)) # 2024
```

Comment: а на 2020 надо вывести 2024, а не 2020

Comment: не, тогда на невисокосные неправильный результат. Вот так вроде работает ny = ``y+4 if isleap(y) else y + 4 - y % 4``

Comment: ну так 2018 не високосный совсем :)

Comment: На сколько подробная нужна проверка? Например, 2100 год не будет високосным, хоть и делится на 4 ,а 2400 - будет...

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов isleap() уже достаточно корректно проверяет :)

Comment: @Эникейщик Не знаю питон, по сему допускаю, что чего-то не понимаю. Но если я правильно понял код, то мне сложно представить число, которое делится на 400, и при этом не делится на сто.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов а зачем вам это представлять? И какое отношение это имеет к вопросу? В коде выше нет ни 100, ни 400.

Comment: `print(next_leap(2098)) # 2100` - что-то не так.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru хехе, отличный тест!

Comment: @TigerTV.ru поправил.

Comment: @Эникейщик, они есть в коде, проведенном в вопросе.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов ну так и спрашивайте в комментарии к вопросу,  не?

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант:

```py
from calendar import isleap

def next_leap(y):
    res = y + 4 - y % 4
    return res + 4 * (not isleap(res))

print(next_leap(1998)) # 2000
print(next_leap(2020)) # 2024
print(next_leap(2098)) # 2104
```